# How to mock ActivatedRouteSnapshot when testing an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test an observable from a service in Angular. The observable will return a boolean depending on the queryParam value.

In order to test the observable, the queryParam needs to be mocked.

The expects from the test file return false in both cases, as it doesn't get any queryParam value.

This is the service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BirdService {
  private readonly _bird$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.birdStatus);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public get bird$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._bird$.asObservable();
  }

  private get birdStatus(): boolean {
    const isBird = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('bird') === 'true';
    if (isBird) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the test file:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { BirdService } from './birdService.service';


describe('BirdService', () => {
  let service: BirdService;
  let route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [BirdService],
    });
    route = new ActivatedRouteSnapshot();
  });

  describe('When there is a bird', () => {
    it('should enable the flying mode', (done) => {
      route.queryParams = {
        bird: 'true',
      };
      service = TestBed.inject(BirdService);

      service.bird$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        expect(value).toBe(true);
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  describe('there is NO bird', () => {
    it('should NOT enable the flying mode', (done) => {
      route.queryParams = {
        bird: 'false',
      };
      service = TestBed.inject(BirdService);

      service.bird$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        expect(value).toBe(false);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routed-components?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It does not provide a solution for a queryParam snapshot, which is not an observable. The case in the link is an observable with a paramMap.

Comment: But it shows how to provide a test double for the activated route. If you aren't using the observable API, it's even easier to create than the example. Also why doesn't `get birdStatus` just `return this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('bird') === 'true';`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `get birdStatus` cannot just `return this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('bird') === 'true';`. In that case it would always return true. `get birdStatus` check if that condition is met, if it is not met, it  returns false.

Comment: What? `===` comparison returns a boolean, either `true` or `false`, then you check if that boolean is truth-y (which given only two values means... `true`) and if so return `true` or if false-y (...`false`) return `false` - that's totally pointless. Even in cases where you _don't_ have a boolean, `return !!(whatever)` is more idiomatic than `if (whatever) { return true } else { return false }`.

Comment: Yes. I have it like that, because more conditions are going to come.

Answer (score -1):

So I found a solution to this problem, in case anyone ends up in this post.

```
describe('BirdService', () => {
  let service: BirdService;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        BirdService,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              queryParamMap: {
                get: () => 'true',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
  });

  describe('When there is a bird', () => {
    it('should enable the flying mode', (done) => {
      service = TestBed.inject(BirdService);

      service.bird$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        expect(value).toBe(true);
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  describe('there is NO bird', () => {
    it('should NOT enable the flying mode', (done) => {
      spyOn(route.snapshot.queryParamMap, 'get').and.returnValue('false');

      service = TestBed.inject(BirdService);

      service.bird$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        expect(value).toBe(false);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```